# Access Denied when running Windows Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have created a Windows Service using ASP.Net Core 3.x and C#.  I started with the new Windows Service template when I built the project.  When I run it from my development environment or from a console window  it runs fine.  When I install it as a Windows Service and attempt to start the service I get an 
"Error 5: Access is denied." error.

I tried numerous things which I will outline below to eliminate the error but nothing seemed to work so I downloaded the sample app provided by Microsoft, at [sample](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/host-and-deploy/windows-service/samples/3.x/BackgroundWorkerServiceSample)

Same result...when I run the sample app from within Visual Studio it runs fine, when running as a service I get the Access Denied error.

- I am running all of this on my local machine, which I am an admin on.
- I originally tried to run it using the default Local System account; got the Access Denied error.
  I changed the Log On As to my domain account, the same one I use to log into my local machine which is an admin on this machine; got the same Access Denied error.
- My account has the privilege set to run as a service.
- The Event Viewer just shows the one message which says "Access Denied", no other messages are created.
- I believe the Access Denied error is occurring before the C# code is even executed.  What makes me believe this is that I added one line to the very top of the Program.Main.... `File.WriteAllText("C:\\temp\\ws.log", $"Test of Worker Service @ {DateTime.Now}. Content Root Path: {AppContext.BaseDirectory}");`.  My account has full access to the temp folder.  This file gets created when I run the app from Visual Studio but it does not get created when I run the app as a service.
- I have read numerous web sites, include this [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) and this [one](https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2019/10/15/windowsservice/).  No luck, everything I tried from these sites still produce the Access Denied error.

I have run out of ideas and am hoping someone here can provide me the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I think OP created a web project and tries to host it as awindows service

Comment: do a simple repro and push it to a GitHub so we can repro.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution and believe me I feel really stupid!!!

When I installed it as a service I only put the path in "binPath".

`sc create WindowsService1 binPath="C:\temp"`.

Once I actually added the executable to the binPath parameter everything worked.

Changed it to `sc create WindowsService1 binPath="C:\temp\WindowsService.exe"` and it worked.

I know it is an Id10t error but Microsoft should really provide better messaging for the "sc" command.  A message like "Cannot find file specified in the binPath parameter" would have been really helpful.  Would have saved me about 6 hours of work.

Thanks everyone for reviewing and replying to this question.